# Building QT5.4 without android on windows 7

Tags: qt

I could build entire QT on windows. 
Now I have to build QTCore without android. 
I see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/licensing.html) that QTCore has a component that links to Android c++ run time and I have to skip building that component.

I am not sure if I get android capabilities if I build it simply using :

```
configure -nomake tests -nomake examples -opensource
nmake
```